# D3 Y Axis Scaling with Line path transition

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I've been very closely following this [post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQoBc.gif) about D3 line transitions, implementing something similar to this.

The end goal is to display real time line chart with yAxis auto scaling.

I have defined rendering logic , like so:

per ticks

```
const tick = () => {
    r += 1;
    const randomDigit = random();

    data.push(randomDigit);

    const p = d3.select(".line").node();

    const yMin = d3.min(data, d => d);
    const yMax = d3.max(data, d => d);

    y.domain([yMin, yMax]);

    if (g.selectAll(".axis.axis--y").empty()) {
      g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    } else {
      g.selectAll(".axis.axis--y")
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }


    d3.select(p)
      .enter()
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line)
      .attr("transform", null);

    d3.active(p)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
      .transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("d", line)
      .on("start", tick);

    data.shift();
  };
```

but the chart looks strange.

it has wiggle problem like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQoBc.gif)

is there any recommendation to solve it?

Thank you for reading my problem!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?